# Laravel 5.4 displaying different post on different url

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

This is a weird one to me...I have a show method in my PostController:

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
  return view('post.show', compact('post'));
}
```

Now when I do a `dd($post)` without returning the show view, I get the correct post. But when the view is rendered, it is displaying content for a different post entirely...eventhough the url is still pointing to the intended post. So if I wanted to show `post-1` for instance, the url is loaded correctly (`mysite.com/posts/post-1`), but the content displayed on the page from `{!! $page->body !!}` is from a different post (`eg from post-2`). Never experienced this before...any thoughts will be helpful.

Comment: are you caching things and retrivieving any cached information in post/show.blade?

Comment: No I am not caching anything. I have even cleared the cache and views `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` and I still get the same result.

Comment: Can you share your route bindings and your view code?